# Is this lvalue returning dangerous?

Tags: c++, templates, c++14

I have this code:

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : public Base {
  int somedata;
};

std::unique_ptr<Base> createTemporary() {
  return std::make_unique<Derived>(); // This code has been simplified
}

template<typename T>
T& convertValueTo(std::unique_ptr<Base>&& obj) {
 return static_cast<T&>(*obj); 
}

int main() {
    int data = convertValueTo<Derived>(createTemporary()).somedata;
    return 0;
}
```

I designed the `convertValueTo` templated function to return the asked type of the object and mostly for function calls like

```
auto some_value = convertValueTo<Something_Else>(createTemporary()).a_member_variable;
```

Now I'm wondering.. is there a safer way to do this? If someone were to use the returned reference from `convertValueTo`, the temporary will be destroyed as soon as the line expression ends right?

My goal is:

- Allow the use of a temporary and destroy it as soon as possible if the reference is not stored (as above)
- Allow a safe reference binding to a valid object in case someone wants to

Comment: What returned reference? Looks like `convertValueTo` returns a copy of the derived type object.

Comment: You are not returning by reference but by value.  This means a copy will be made and it will be independent from `convertValueTo`

Comment: You return type `T`, not `T&`.

Comment: Since your `convertValueTo` function accepts an rvalue reference, why don't you simply convert to a `unique_ptr<SomethingElse>` and return that one?

Comment: Had a typo in the code, in the codebase I'm returning `&`

Comment: Dynamically creating an object (unique_ptr) and then trying to handle it statically (T&) cannot work. When and by whom is it supposed to be destroyed?

Comment: I'd like it to be destroyed right away after grabbing/using its values (or moving from them). Anyway it would be cool to be able to keep it for some other time in case I wanted to do something first (and bind it to a reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert to a `unique_ptr` of the required type. Then it is clear who has ownership of the dynamically created object, namely the `unique_ptr` returned from the conversion function. As soon as you create an lvalue reference to the dynamically created object, there will be the possibility that the reference survives the lifetime of your object.

```
#include <memory>


struct Base {};
struct Derived : public Base {
  int somedata;
};

std::unique_ptr<Base> createTemporary() {
  return std::make_unique<Derived>(); // This code has been simplified
}

template<typename T>
std::unique_ptr<T> convertValueTo(std::unique_ptr<Base>&& obj) {
  auto ptr = obj.release ();
  return std::unique_ptr<T> { static_cast<T*>(ptr) }; 
}

int main() {
  int data = convertValueTo<Derived>(createTemporary())->somedata;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: A small explanation to help us focus on the main feature of your answer ?